# Error opening the application in testflight - Flutter | iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

I developed an application in flutter and submitted it to testflight.
On most iPhone models tested, the app opened correctly. However, on some models, the application does not go beyond the splash that is displayed at the beginning of the app. And this error occurs:

> AMSURLSession: [7BB9652E] Session decoder failed. Result = (null); Error = Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code, AMSURL=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/commerce/messages/app/inbox?bundleId=br.com.project....&guid=0000432238110-0012401E&status=1, AMSStatusCode=410, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code}

The error occurs on these two iPhone models:

1. IPhone 13 Pro Max com IOS 16.7.1
2. iPhone 12 com  IOS 17.0.3

Has this problem ever happened to you?